# First time using an API: How do I construct a request for the proper data from a quote API? Links included

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am using this API from Stands4 to get quotes. I was able to build my random quote generator for free code camp using their RANDOM tag in the request. Now I want to know how to write a request to get quote from a tv show for a personal project I am working on. Does anyone know how this is possible?

Here is the API doc: [Link](http://www.quotes.net/quotes_api.php)

In particular I am looking at the second and third lines of their Request parameters table. I want to use 'SEARCH' but don't know how to produce the correct 'query'. Maybe I am going about this wrong.

Here is the show I would like to get quotes from: [Link](http://www.quotes.net/show/776)

Here is what I tried. Goal is to get a random quote from the show.

```
http://www.stands4.com/services/v2/quotes.php?uid=MYUID&tokenid=MYTOKENID&searchtype=RANDOM&SEARCH&query=Its+Always+Sunny+In+Philadelphia
```

Comment: Please share the code you've been trying so far and got stuck with

Comment: @baao edited with code I tried

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, these aren't the greatest docs so you'll have to play around with the "query=" part of your search. **You're correct in thinking that's where to start.**

Here's the approach I would take to make this work:

**1. Searchtype=Search:** I would start subbing in all sorts of different things from It's always Sunny and seeing what gets returned, including: character names, the show name, writer/actor names, and if all else fails show objects ("Paddy's pub" and "Day man") come to mind. Note: for things with spaces make sure you're using url-encoding.

**2. Searchtype=Author:** Take writer names and maybe character names to see if putting those in with an author search type returns anything.

**3. Use their Scripts API:** I'd hope something would come from that, but if it doesn't work, you can always try and find some scripts from their [Scripts API](http://www.scripts.com/scripts_api.php) and parse them.

If all else fails you can use a scraping tool like [Import.io](https://www.import.io/) and grab quotes from a site like IMDB. Import.io is free and very easy to use.